# Text above a floated element float wraps

Tags: css

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqr8h/).

I want the `h4` element to wrap around the floated element, **without changing the document flow** and **without giving the `h4` a set width**.

You will notice that if you move the floated element above the `h4`, it behaves the way I want it to.

The reason I need to do it this way is that the site is responsive, so I can't rely on the width of the `h4` and the floated element needs to be an exact width.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this seems impossible with your given limitations.

Comment: i can't understand wht u want. if u can add a rough image.

Comment: This isn't possible with giving the h4 a width, whether px or %

Comment: moving the floated element above 'h4' solves your problem, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the other answer and comments, it is indeed not possible to do this without moving the `.floated-element` above `h4` or giving the `h4` a width.

Answer (score 2):

Make the text `clear:none;` and move the `.floated-element` above the `h4`.

CSS

```
.text {
    clear: none;
    display: block;                   
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="floated-element"></div>
<h4>This is a long title that needs to wrap around the floated element</h4>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqr8h/6/

Comment: Thanks for answer iambriansreed, but I was looking for a way to do it without changing the document flow, as specified above.